# TypeScript - Spread types may only be created from object types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Code below throws `Spread types may only be created from object types`:

```
const bool = true

console.log({ ...(bool || { foo: 'bar' }) })
```

While the following works fine, what caused the above error and how to suppress it?

```
const bool = true

console.log({ ...(bool && { foo: 'bar' }) })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do the `||`, it evaluates the item on the left and tries to spread it. But it cannot spread a boolean variable, it can only spread an object.

When you do the `&&`, the expression in parens returns the `{ foo: 'bar' }` object, which is spreadable.

To play with this, try:

```
console.log(true && 'hi') // "hi"
console.log(true || 'hi') // true
```

Comment: To pass this error, we have to do sth like `console.log({ ...(<any>(bool || { foo: 'bar' })) })`? Is there another way?

Comment: No that will just make a runtime error when the boolean value gets spread. What do you want to happen if the bool is true or false?

Comment: No, it won't, just give it a go.

Comment: You are right, it does not give an error. But it doesn't smell good! Maybe this reads better?

console.log(bool ? { foo: 'bar' } : {})

Answer (score 1):

**The first one translate like this**

If bool is true or the object... In that case it's trying to spread the bool but seeing that bool is a Boolean not an object... You get the error

**The second translate like this**

If bool is true, then spread this object... The ampersand in that case is doing a check, making sure bool is true before spreading the object... This is equivalent to writing an if statement...

if (bool) console.log({ ...{ foo: 'bar' } })